Establish a bijection between two sets of solutions
It is well known that the equations $x_0 + x_1 + \cdots + x_n = m$ and $y_0 + y_1 + \cdots + y_m = n$ have the same number of non-negative integer solutions. This follows from the fact that the coefficient of $z^m$ in $\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}$ is the same as the coefficient of $z^n$ in $\frac{1}{(1-z)^{m+1}}$. Another way to prove it is to swap the  stars and bars  in the stars and bars model.
Question: How can we establish a bijection $(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto (y_0, y_1, \ldots, y_m)$ between the solutions?

They're both in bijection with the set of partitions / Young diagrams that fit into an $n \times m$ rectangle. Take the partial sums. The bijection is rotating the Young diagrams.

(I should clarify, you take the partial sums but excluding the last one. $x_n$ and $y_m$ respectively are redundant.)

You already established a bijection; convert to stars and bars, then switch stars with bars. Why doesn’t that just count as an answer?

@Mike Earnest  I want to have an explicit formula that expresses $y$' in terms of $x$'

@Qiaochu Yuan  please turn your comment into an answer with an example for small $n,m$

The partial sums $x_0, x_0 + x_1, \dots, x_0 + x_1 + \dots + x_{m-1}$ form a partition, which you can visualize as a Young diagram (in French notation but flipped horizontally). This Young diagram fits into an $n \times m$ rectangle (equivalently, the partition consists of at most $m$ parts of size at most $n$), and this is a bijection between tuples $x_i$ and such Young diagrams.
The same argument shows that the partial sums $y_0, y_0 + y_1, \dots , y_0 + y_1 + \dots + y_{n-1}$ form a partition corresponding to a Young diagram fitting into an $m \times n$ rectangle, and this is also a bijection.
Now the bijection between these is just given by rotating the Young diagrams. This is probably equivalent to what you get from the stars-and-bars argument. It works out explicitly to the following: $y_i$ is the number of terms of the sequence of partial sums $s_j = x_0 + \dots + x_j$ equal to $m - i$.
Let's work through the explicit example of the following Young diagram I took from Wikipedia:
                                                                       
We'll read it right-to-left to get the $x_i$, then read it bottom-to-top to get the $y_i$. Reading right-to-left we get that the sequence of partial sums of the $x_i$ is $1, 2, 2, 2, 3$, so the sequence $x_i$ itself is $\boxed{ 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 }$. So here $n = 5, m = 3$ and I am ignoring the last term $x_n$ which is equal to $0$.
Reading bottom-to-top (which is equivalent to rotating the Young diagram) we get that the sequence of partial sums of the $y_i$ is $1, 4, 5$, so the sequence $y_i$ itself is $\boxed{ 1, 3, 1 }$. Again I am ignoring the last term $y_m$ which is equal to $0$. And you can check that as claimed, $y_0$ is the number of partial sums of the $x_i$ equal to $3$, $y_1$ is the number of partial sums equal to $2$, and $y_2$ is the number of partial sums equal to $1$. This just comes from looking at what happens when you rotate the Young diagram and read it as a partition.

Thabk you! A very interesting approach, but some points are not entirely clear. How should we handle solutions that contain zeros at the beginning or end, which you ignore? How can they be represented with Young diagrams? For example, which Young diagram corresponds to the solution $(3,0,0)$  - $(3,3,3)$? How then to obtain the result of the bijection $(0,0,0,2)$ and vice versa?

@Leox: you use the same Young diagram, just with a larger value of $m$ and/or $n$. The values of $m$ and $n$ are part of the data. Said another way you can explicitly draw the bounding rectangle if that would make it clearer. Sometimes this will introduce extra zeroes, which is not a problem. I am ignoring the last term because it's determined by the other terms together with $m$ and $n$, so it's redundant.
